# SilverStripe insertHeadTags in a DataExtension

Tags: php, silverstripe

How do you insert custom html into the  of the back-end, through a DataExtension? I tried placing the `Requirements` call in the `init()` function, but that didn't work.

```
class SomeExtension extends DataExtension {

    public function init() {
    parent::init();

    Requirements::insertHeadTags("
        <style>
            ...
        </style>
    ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `init()`, use `__construct`

```
public function __construct() {

    Requirements::insertHeadTags("
        <style>
            ...
        </style>
    ");

    parent::__construct();
}
```